# Android SDK, check if cached copy is being shown

Tags: javascript, java, android, caching, android-webview

I'm trying to detect if the user is seeing a cached page or error page for lack of cached copy while offline I've tried using `webview.getTitle()` and `webview.getUrl()` but they give the title or url of the last page even in `onPageFinished()` I've also tried using javascript but it takes too long to return the title. `javascript:Android.pageStatus(window.location.href)`

Is there either a way to get the javascript to return a value faster or another way to get current page title.

[The project in case the mistake is on my end](https://github.com/JoshuaWierenga/School-App/tree/web/SchoolWebApp/app/src/main/java/com/joshuawierenga/schoolwebapp)